# How to make view appear over button? Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

What I do to display a view when a user taps on something I hide a view out of sight and then slide it in. It slides over my segment control but not over my button. 
[image]
The second image shows my slide event going over the segment control but not the button leaving the button there which looks awkward. How can I show a slide coming from the right that appears over all my components including my today button?
[image]

here is my code to show the slide controller.

```
    self.eventsViewController = nil;
    self.eventsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"eventsViewController"];
    self.eventsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y, 700, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self addChildViewController:self.eventsViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.eventsViewController.view];
    [self.eventsViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.44 animations: ^(void){
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
        {
            self.eventsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(200 , 75 ,568 ,900);
        } else {
            self.eventsViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(333 , 75 ,690 ,630);
        }

}];
```

**edit: image of eventsViewController with colour**

[image]

Comment: I think this `[self.eventsViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];` is not needed..

Comment: Not even this line `[self addChildViewController:self.eventsViewController];`

Comment: Can you try and change the `backgroundcolor` of `self.eventsViewController.view` and see whether actually it is covering that space ? On same color it is difficult to understand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to bring your view to front?

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.eventsViewController.view];
```

Or send to back your button.

Comment: I don't think this is case, because he is adding the controller view in the end so, the view is already on top, no need to make it again top, its something different.

Comment: [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.todayButton]; did the trick. I agree with iphonic that the button should have been at the back when I add the view on top of the view controller but for some weird reason its not.

Comment: The [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.eventsViewController.view]; didn't work though.